# Spring @Async is not working

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, spring-async

I am using Spring 3.2.2.RELEASE version . The @Async anotation is not working as expected .

> applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">


<!-- Enable AspectJ style of Spring AOP -->
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>



    <context:component-scan base-package="com.pratik" />



    <tx:annotation-driven />
```

> import.java

```
    public String async() {
    final String asssetImportId = ObjectId.get().toHexString();

      process.asyncTest();

    logger.info("Ongoing");
    return asssetImportId;
  }
```

> process.java

```
@Async
  public void asyncTest() {
    try {
      Thread.sleep(1000);

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    logger.info("After Sleep");

  }
```

The **After Sleep** log should print last but it is getting printed before **ongoing**

Comment: `Thread.sleep should be (1000)`, are both these methods in the same class

Comment: Lots of possibilities here. You haven't showed turning on async support (you're on an obsolete version of Spring). You haven't showed where you get the `process` variable from. You're sleeping for zero time.

Comment: Usage of `@Async` requires you to add the `@EnableAsync` annotation to one of your `@Configuration` classes.

Comment: @RahulSingh , No these are in different classes .  Thread.sleep(1000) is typo .

Comment: as the configuration is loaded from applicationContext.xml so i have used  <tx:annotation-driven />  to enable @Async

Comment: @AndyBrown ,I am using applicationContext.xml for configuration . and used tx:annotation-driven  to enable Async

Answer (score 0):

Thread.sleep(000) seems a typo to me. in case apo allows you to do ste a 0 sleep, this would be a good reason for the print to happen before what you expected (maybe not always, since you are talking about Async any "order" of prints might happen)

**Edit:** tx:annotation-driven is for transactional support. Add context:annotation-config

**Edit2:** Correction: use "task:annotation-driven (not to confuse with tx namespace)

Comment: I have changed code and made Thread.sleep(5000) . Still it works like single threaded model only .

Comment: how are you retrieving "process" bean? you don't show that part of the code

Comment: Process bean is autowired . I have used  spring @component anotation

Comment: are you sure "tx:annotation-driven" is the lnly thing you need? that would seem related mainly to transactional stuff annotations, and async might be left aside. better add the context:annotation-config one also

Comment: can you post your edited xml config (including new namespace declarations)? also, just in case, your classes are under "com.patril" package isn't it?